# Serialize object of multiple classes into a single JSON using Json.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, json.net

I want to join objects of several classes together into a single JSON response, using Json.NET.  I want to build the following into a single JSON response:

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "from": {
        "name": "Pawan Shrestha",
        "id": "100001187416487"
      },
      "created_time": "2012-04-22T10:21:22+0000",
      "unread": true,
      "to": {
        "name": "Shashwat Tripathi",
        "id": "100000559654730"
      }
    }
  ],
  "summary": {
    "unread_count": 1,
    "total_count": 1,
    "updated_time": "2012-04-22T10:21:22+0000"
  }
  "response_generated_on" : "2012-04-12 14:23:33"
}
```

I am creating JSON responses in the following way:

```
Customer cs = new Customer(2011); //2011 is Customer A/c No.
string j = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(cs);
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can use anonymous types:

```
JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new {
    data = new[] { ... },
    summary = ...
});
```

Comment: How would you do the revert operation though? ie. How would you deserialize the generated Json? Thanks